# Searchphrase not working for one of the column in bootstrap table

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have modified following function to search string in multiple columns and display records. But when I have added `$where .=" OR tester LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' )";` for able to search in `tester` column, search function does not show output.
So what I want is:
1. Enable search in `tester` column also.
2. If searchphrase does not match with data in table. It should give output- as "No records found".

```
    function getRecords($params) {
    $rp = isset($params['rowCount']) ? $params['rowCount'] : 10;

    if (isset($params['current'])) { $page  = $params['current']; } else { $page=1; };  
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $rp;

    $sql = $sqlRec = $sqlTot = $where = '';

    if( !empty($params['searchPhrase']) ) {   
        $where .=" WHERE ";
        $where .=" ( date LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";    
        $where .=" OR version LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR test_type LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' )";
        // when added following line it's not working
        $where .=" OR tester LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' )";
   }
   if( !empty($params['sort']) ) {  
        $where .=" ORDER By ".key($params['sort']) .' '.current($params['sort'])." ";
    }
   // getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `workflow1` ";
    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;

    //concatenate search sql if value exist
    if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }
    if ($rp!=-1)
    $sqlRec .= " LIMIT ". $start_from .",".$rp;


    $qtot = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlTot) or die("error to fetch tot employees data");
    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) { 
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $json_data = array(
        "current"            => intval($params['current']), 
        "rowCount"            => 10,            
        "total"    => intval($qtot->num_rows),
        "rows"            => $data   // total data array
        );

    return $json_data;
}
```

Comment: does the query work when used directly e.g. in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Try get your sqlTot and sqlRec and execute them manually.

Comment: you copied the previous line but did not remove the closing bracket from that line.

Comment: Thanks all for quick reply. @inarilo Yes, now it works after removing closing bracket. Can you suggest something for my second question i.e. if no result found.

Comment: in the frontend just check the array size of rows. if 0 show error message. or you seem to be sending it as total, if 0, show error.